# Django CORS issues

Tags: angularjs, django, cors

I'm currently developing something and running into Django CORS issues. I've followed [this](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to try solving this issue but I don't seem to be having any luck when I want to include a whitelist in. I continuously get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." when I try to do a GET request onto the database.

Specifically, I'm developing an angular web app that's hosted on a different domain (AWS S3) while the Django db is on AWS EC2. The whitelisting works locally when I whitelist localhost:3000, for example, but doesn't seem to work when I whitelist the s3 domain. It does work if I set the Django to allow all but I don't want to do that for security purposes. I'm currently trying to add in some regular expressions to the domain to allow the different routes available on the website, but that still doesn't explain why localhost:3000 worked when it's more of localhost:3000/#/page/page2.

My javascript code is as follows:

```
$http({
    url: "api/url",
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'accesstoken'
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    $scope.response = response;
  }, (data) => {
    $scope.response = data;
  })
```

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the regex whitelist works. Following the documentation on django cors headers, simply include the regex for your domain and it'll work for any routes that you try to access the Django db on. Not sure why the localhost worked but this didn't, nor did adding the route specifically as a whitelist, but I'm not complaining.